# Can I use the verb pass with another verb

Tags: sentence-construction

Which one of the following sentences grammatically to correct?

> I saw a man who passed in the front of house by running.
>
> I saw a man who passed running in front of the house.

or I can only use an adverb as in the following.

> I saw man who passed very fast in  front of the house .

Comment: I'd write: *I saw a man passing from the front of my house running!*

Comment: When we say *X passed by [Y]* the implication is almost always *passed **slowly** by*, so it's not idiomatic to include *any* adjectival modifier denoting "rapidity". If the "passing by" happens very quickly, you'd probably use a different verb, such as ***flashed by***. Or in your context, *a man **ran past** the house*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your sentences are grammatically correct, except the last which should say "a man" and not "man".

However, keep in mind that another meaning of *pass* (which can also be the phrasal verb *pass away* but *away* is optional) can be a polite form of "die".

> I'm sorry to hear of your grandfather's passing yesterday.

A way to make it clear that you don't mean this is to say *pass by* and keep the *by* prepositional phrase close to the verb, if there is one:

> I saw a man who passed by running in the front of house
>
> I saw a man who passed by the front of the house, running.
>
> I saw a man who passed by very fast in front of the house.

Basically, you can treat *pass by* like a phrasal verb.

Of couse, earlier context may make it 100% clear that you are talking about a person moving past a house and not dying, so one might say *passed* and not *passed by*, but it's good to include it if someone may not know the context for clarity.